# I'm Confused About Naming Between Sap Odata and Sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, abap

https://blogs.sap.com/2015/02/05/simple-exercise-on-odata-and-sap-ui5-application-for-the-basic-crud-operation/

I'm trying to make my own sapui5 project based on project above. But I'm so much confused about field naming in data base. There is too much names similar to each other(they represent each other but I just don't understand which one I'm using in abap and which one I'm using in js).

Can someone please highlight it? At least I should understand relation between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the project new DB table ZMM_EMP created. Data model use source parameters imported from the table. Fields for mapping are provided by function modules with names IV_* and ET_*.